# How to change audio mode programmatically only when notification is happening in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

I want to ask how to change audio mode temporarily only when notification is happening?

For instance, I want my current mode is silent, no sound and no vibration. When notification is happening sound volume is max and with vibration. After notification is done, I want to change it back to silent mode without sound and vibration.

The problem is, I can change from silent to max volume and with vibration, but the audio settings still max sound with vibration after the notification is done.

This is my code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
                             audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION),
                             AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(GCMHandler.MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                           NotificationBuilder.build(context,
                                                     "Mohon konfirmasi booking #" + bookings.last().getCode(),
                                                     "Booking #"+bookings.last().getCode()+" belum dikonfirmasi!",
                                                     NotificationBuilder.Type.PUSH_NOTIFICATION,
                                                     R.drawable.notif_icon, 0xFFC200));
```

and if I put `audioManager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT)` after `notificationManager.notify()`, the notification just built with full silent mode

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

** I think this code will helps to default ringtone in mobile
   if you are in silent mode it will vibrate other wise default notification tone

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.piconebg)
            .setContentTitle(title)
             .setSubText(title3)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
         .setColor(color)
            .setStyle(new       NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(PushNotificationService.this.getResources(), R.drawable.push))
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id /* ID of notification unique */,notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder has nothing to do with that. I've tried it before with setSound and setVibrate, nothing happend if my initial mode is silent. As far as I know, setSound is only about what kind of sound you'll play when the notification arise.

Thx for the response

Answer (score 0):

I also want to handle this problem. You can use the delete intent to set the mode back in the related broadcast receiver:

```
private fun createNotification(context: Context, channelId: String) {
    val intent = Intent("my.package.notification_closed_action")
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
    intent.putExtra("notification_id", noticationId)
    intent.setPackage(context.packageName)
    val deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    
    val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
       ...
       .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
       ...
}
```